# Kubernetes: How to create ingress type networkpolicy to allow only access to labeled pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have the following `deployment`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: redis
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: redis:alpine
        name: redis
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

**Question 1 :** How do you expose this deployment via a `ClusterIP` service on port 8080.

**Question 2 :** How would I create a new Ingress Type `NetworkPolicy` to allows only the pods with label `access=redis` to access the deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 6379
```

Network Policy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access: redis
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
```